# How to mock a class with non virtual function with CppUMock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, cpputest

I'm writing unit tests with CppUTest & CppUMock framework.

Here is a example of what I have :

```cpp
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA(ClassB &classB);
}
```

```cpp
class ClassB
{
public:
    ClassB();
    void DoingThings(void);
}
```

I want to unit test ClassA. The thing is that ClassA is using a reference to ClassB, that's why I'd like to mock ClassB.

My problem is that ClassB doesn't contain any virtual classes. So inheritance which saved my life until now is not working this time.
Indeed until now I only had ClassB inheriting from interfaces which was pretty convenient because I could write ClassBMock inheriting from the same interface.

My question is how to mock ClassB (using CppUTest/CppUMock framework) ?

Comment: make `ClassB` inherit from some interface?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number This would mean modifying my production code to test it which seems counter productive ?

Comment: writing testable code is not counter productive. If your code is hard to test then you better modify it